# PowerShell script efficiency advice

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a telephony .csv with compiled data from January 2020 and some days of February, each row has the date and time spent on each status, since someone uses different status over the day the file has one row for each status, my script is supposed to go through the file, find the minimum date and then start saving on new files all the data for the same day, so I'll end with one file for 01-01-2020, 02-01-2020 and so on, but it has 15 hours running and it's still at 1/22.

The column I'm using for the dates is called "DateFull" and this is the script

```
write-host "opening file" 
$AT= import-csv “C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\SignOnOff_20200101_20200204.csv” 
write-host "parsing and sorting file" 
$go= $AT| ForEach-Object {
        $_.DateFull= (Get-Date $_.DateFull).ToString("M/d/yyyy")
        $_
        }
    
Write-Host "prep day"
$min = $AT | Measure-Object -Property Datefull  -Minimum  

Write-Host $min
$dateString =  [datetime] $min.Minimum
Write-host $datestring

write-host "Setup dates"
$start = $DateString - $today
$start = $start.Days

For ($i=$start; $i -lt 0; $i++)  {
$date = get-date
$loaddate = $date.AddDays($i) 
$DateStr = $loadDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
$now = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
write-host $datestr " " $now

#Install-Module ImportExcel #optional import if you dont have the module already
$Check = $at | where {$_.'DateFull' -eq $datestr} 
write-host $check.count
if ($check.count -eq 0 ){}
else {$AT | where {$_.'DateFull' -eq $datestr} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\signonoff\SignOnOff_$(get-date (get-date).addDays($i) -f yyyyMMdd).csv" -NoTypeInformation}
}

$at = ''
```

Comment: How big is the CSV? @Jawad unless the source data is huge, the code might have infinite loop or unexpected O.

Comment: it's a 50 MB file

Comment: Can you add a few lines of sample data from a CSV with desired results?

Comment: I see that you have `Get-Date` used in a couple places simply to get today's date inside the `for loop`. You can assign the value of `Get-Date` to a variable outside the loop and then call the variable instead in place of the `cmdlet`.

Comment: Also,`[datetime]"11/11/2019"` is more efficient than `Get-date "11/11/2019"`. Also the IO operation inside the `else loop` could be slowing u down. If you can refactor that logic, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop doesn't make much sense. It loops through CSV contents and converts each row's date into different a format. Afterwards, `$go` is never used.

```
$go= $AT| ForEach-Object {
        $_.DateFull= (Get-Date $_.DateFull).ToString("M/d/yyyy")
        $_
        }
```

Later, there is an attempt to calculate a value from uninitialized a variable. `$today` is never defined.

```
$start = $DateString - $today
```

It looks, however, like you'd like to calculate, in days, how old eldest record is.

Then there's a loop that counts from negative days to zero. During each iteration, the whole CSV is searched:

```
$Check = $at | where {$_.'DateFull' -eq $datestr}
```

If there are 30 days and 15 000 rows, there are 30*15000 = 450 000 iterations. This has complexity of O(n^2), which means runtime will go sky high for even relative small number of days and rows.

The next part is that the same array is processed again:

```
else {$AT | where {$_.'DateFull' -eq $datestr
```

Well, the search condition is exactly the same, but now results are sent to a file. This has a side effect of doubling your work. Still, O(2n^2) => O(n^2), so at least the runtime isn't growing in cubic or worse.

As for how to fix this, there are a few things. If you sort the CSV based on date, it can be processed afterwards in just a single run.

```
$at = $at | sort -Property datefull
```

Then, iterate each row. Since the rows are in ascending order, the first is the oldest. For each row, check if date has changed. If not, add it to buffer. If it has, save the old buffer and create a new one.

The sample doesn't convert file names in yyyyMMdd format, and it assumes there are only two columns `foo` and `datefull` like so,

```
$sb = new-object text.stringbuilder
# What's the first date?
$current = $at[0]

# Loop through sorted data
for($i = 0; $i -lt $at.Count; ++$i) {

    # Are we on next date?
    if ($at[$i].DateFull -gt $current.datefull) {
        # Save the buffer
        $file = $("c:\temp\OnOff_{0}.csv" -f ($current.datefull -replace '/', '.') )
        set-content $file $sb.tostring()
        # Pick the current date
        $current = $at[$i]

        # Create new buffer and save data there
        $sb = new-object text.stringbuilder
        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0},{1}" -f $at[$i].foo, $at[$i].datefull))    
    } else {
        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0},{1}" -f $at[$i].foo, $at[$i].datefull))    
    }
}
# Save the final buffer
$file = $("c:\temp\OnOff_{0}.csv" -f ($current.datefull -replace '/', '.') )
set-content $file $sb.tostring()
```

Comment: I knew I had some things wrong in there but didn't realize it was that much haha. thanks for your observations, I'll take them into account in the future, I have a question tho, I tried to run this script just changing the $file path and adding the columns on my file to the string, but I noticed that it rewrites the original file, I need to keep the original file unchanged and create individual files for each day. how can I do that? or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jhilbran Since the sample writes files in `c:\temp\OnOff_...` and your source has altogether different a name and location, the culprit likely is in your code. It's easier to debug that problem if you post a new question that demonstrates the problem. Don't change this one, as SO's idea is to have Q&A pairs. Changing the original question makes answers irrelevant.